# Protecting credits from being removed

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to protect my source code when deployed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826672/how-to-protect-my-source-code-when-deployed)

Can you give me some suggestions on how to secure a piece of code (credits, footer) from being removed?

It's just a text saying "Made by", bla bla...
If a user removes that piece of code, I want to force it back on the place or to display a warning message.

Comment: you can't. end of story.

Comment: Voting to reopen since the "duplicate" is not the exact same question.

Comment: Good people, can you explain why are you voting down? The problem seems to be a legit programming and code related issue

Comment: @ZoltanToth: Actually, something like this shouldn't be done in a programmed way but via the license.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Sure licencing your product is a good idea, but just look at Microsoft, Adobe etc. - they all doing enormous efforts to keep their code as protected as possible in addition to all their licences.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about populating a div using javascript? Most users that will hack your theme/code won't understand where its coming from. Try something like appending the div to your body tag so even the div isn't written in html of your code. This might prevent a lot of efforts to remove the credits. What are you building exactly? What is the context? Is it a theme for a cms?

Comment: Another idea is to request an encrypted variable from your own server that is required for your script to work. If they don't match then the whole thing falls over. What type of licence will you release your script with and what do you hope to gain by enforcing credits?

Comment: Script will be completely free to use and edit, but the only requirement is keeping credits. I hope my script will get more users then. Can you give me some link to read more about your idea?

Comment: No code example, just a brain 'fart' at this point. Keeping the credits isn't going to help you at all unless there is a hyperlink to your site where you could at least benefit from traffic. Does your script use javascript at all?

Comment: Credits are actually "Powered by" hyperlink. Yes, script uses javascript/jquery.